# apt-get without sudo?

Tags: apt, python

I am trying to install YouCompleteMe (YCM) on my user account on a Debian machine.
The installation guide says we need python-dev for YCM to work:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

My question is:

How do I install python-dev with out sudo access? I am trying to install YCM on a debian machine where I do not have root access.

Thank you.

Comment: Not possible.  You might install python under your $HOME but you should better ask your sysadmin

Answer (score 1):

Chances are that your system Python is not the latest in the 2.7 or 3.4 line. So you should consider installing the latest **Python** from source. This might bring its own problems as have to install first problems for `-dev` packages that should be installed before you get a useful Python: `libreadline-dev`, `libssl-dev`, `libbz2-dev`, `libexpat1-dev`, `libsqlite3-dev` is probably what you want at least but you might need more and also might not need all of these.

- when you run `./configure` leave out the `--enable-shared` option
- after `make`, be sure to use  `make altinstall` in order not to overwrite your system python

With the latest versions in the 2.7 and 3.4 series you have `pip` make sure you use that pip (use the full path), to

1. upgrade itself (`/path/to/pip install -U pip`)
2. install `virtualenv`: `pip install virtualenv` (on 3.4 you can also use the built-in stuff)

Now you have `virtualenv`, using the full path create a new virtualenv:

```
 /path/to/virtualenv /some/other/path/venv
 source /some/other/path/venv/bin/activate
```

Now you have a python environment in which you can install YCM and it is complete separate from the systems python. You can install new elements with pip (without needing any path, you will get the one from `/some/other/path/venv/bin/` The just installed alternate python has all the header files that normally come separately with `python-dev`

Comment: If they can't get their admin to install a trivially installable package, why do you assume they'll be fine with a whole new copy of Python in a home directory?

Comment: Quite simple, if you have a quota system, and the python install fits within then you can do so without them having to give consent.

Comment: @Anthon, pip, virtualenv? YCM is not a Python module. YCM is a VIM plugin with a compiled component. You should have `python-dev`, `build-essentials`, `cmake` and optionally `libclang` (for semantic completion) to compile it.

Answer (score -1):

I just made a tool for this exact purpose:
https://github.com/z3r0n3t/pkget

She the readme for more info. It's super easy to use, I hope this helps someone.

---

> ## pkget
>
> ---
>
> With this tool you can easily install packages from the apt repository
>   or any other Debian repository wether you have root or not and tinker
>   with them all in your home directory without affecting anything system
>   wide with you don't have to go searching the file system to find your
>   broken dependencies or snoop thru scripts to find what your looking
>   for
>
> ## how to use
>
> ---
>
> using this too is super easy just run setup.sh to move the the grab
>   file to your home directory and makes it executable then it mods your
>   $PATH to to allow the installed tools to be ran without having to
>   switch directorys so instead of “./package_name” you can just run
>   “package_name”
>
> after this is done installing packages is easy just ./pkget
>   “package_to_install”
>
> ## example
>
> ---
>
> ```
> ./pkget xonsh
> ```
>
> ## use cases
>
> ---
>
> this tool is mainly focused on debian package developers and such but also with the mindest of a security person this tool
>   makes its easy for pentesters who get non root control over a server
>   but need to intsall packages  PLEASE USE THIS TOOL FOR GOOD
>
> #DontBeAskid
>
> ## also
>
> if you like it please consider staring it and following me :-) for
>   more cool stuff i have good ideas sometimes